# Replacing same strings but with different string values?

Tags: android, string, android-edittext, replaceall

This is the question.

(1)__ is also a  star.(2)__ revolves around the Sun.

edittext1: _______
edittext2: _______

So in the first blank, I am showing what the user type in edit text.
If he  types Sun,then the output will be like below.

(1)_Sun_is also a  star.(2)__ revolves around the Sun.

edittext1: **Sun**
edittext2: _______

So for (1) I am replacing "__" with my edit text value,as above.
How to do it with (2).
I tried the same logic with (2) but it replaces the first value also.

(1)*Planets* is also a  star.(2)*Planets* revolves around the Sun.

edittext1: ***Sun***

edittext2: **Planets**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ed1,ed2,ed3;
    String edtv1,edtv2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ed1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ed2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        ed3= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        final String sentence = tv.getText().toString();


        if (ed1 != null) {
            ed1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    tv.setText(String.format("%s_", sentence.replace("__", "_" + s.toString())));
                }
            });
            edtv1 = ed1.getText().toString();

        }
        if (ed2 != null) {
            ed2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    tv.setText(String.format("%s_", sentence.replace("__", "_" + s.toString())));
                }
            });
            edtv2 = ed2.getText().toString();

        }


    }
}
```

The above is the full code.

Comment: are you sure you are using the right edit text references ?

Comment: Yes..@harvey_slash.And second time also I am trying to replace"__"So it replace the first one also.

Comment: by 'first one' , i am assuming you mean the first edit text. correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Very very very confusing presentation. Try to format the question to make it clearer.

Comment: I assume the question is written in **one** `TextView`?

Comment: that is because tv seems to be a textview that remains the same. 
are you sure you are change tv inside afterTextChanged to the proper text view for number 2 ?

Comment: The question is on text view and two edit text.So whatever values will be written on edit text 1 and 2 should reflect on the text view.(question)

Comment: can you post the code for edit text 2 as well ? also show what the variable tv is declared to be

Comment: Just wait 2 min  I am updating.

Comment: I updated the question@harvey_slash

Comment: where is the 2nd textview that will be updated by the 2nd edit text ?

Comment: I am trying to update the same textview.Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function below:

```
String s = "1 abc 1 def";
Log.e("Test", replace(s, "1", "1test", "2test")); --> value: 1test abc 2test def
// fuction to replace
private String replace(String source, String toReplace, String... replacements) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(source);
    int startIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < replacements.length; i++) {
        int index = stringBuilder.indexOf(toReplace, startIndex);
        if (startIndex < 0) {
            break;
        }
        stringBuilder.replace(index, index + toReplace.length(), replacements[i]);
        startIndex = index + replacements.length;
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String string = "(1)__ is also a star.(2)__ revolves around the Sun.";
//First do a string split:
// then you'll have an array of strings 
String[] parts = string.split("__");
```

in the 2nd edit text listener, you can change the end of the 2nd element of the parts array. 
In the first, you can change the end of the first element , and so on.

To display, just print out the entire string array

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

You have to make first and second blank different to do accurate replace. You can do this by put different number of underscore

```
String sentence = "(1)___ is also a star.(2)__ revolves around the Sun.";

sentence.replace("___", "Sun");
sentence.replace("__", "Planet");
```

or you can include the number to differentiate the blank

```
String sentence = "(1)__ is also a star.(2)__ revolves around the Sun.";

sentence.replace("(1)__", "(1)" + "Sun");
sentence.replace("(2)__", "(2)" + "Planet");
```

Comment: Actually, I have to fetch it through Url(JSON Parsing).So I can"t change it

Comment: @ShwetabhSingh , you can split the string by the __. depending on the edit text, you can change the corresponding string

Comment: I will try this,but any other solution for this.@harvey_slash